# why more file_name command runs on an encrypted file? I thought "more file_name" command would ask for a password

Tags: file-command

----encrypts a file using
 gpg -c file_name.

more file_name

---Outputs whats in the file.

(Why the file is not secured)

Comment: The encrypted file is `file_name.gpg`, I think? are you sure you are not `more`ing the original file?

Comment: I am mor ing the original file. Will more command display file data even after the encryption?